# Why can't I just use MouseAdapter, not MouseMotionAdapter?

Tags: java, mouseevent

My application's window can be moved around by dragging its menubar. 
However, I don't understand why I have to use MouseMotionAdapter() to implement this feature.

Both classes have the method: mouseDragged(), so I erased MouseMotionAdapter and move the function into the MouseAdapter(). I could not drag the window anymore. Why?

This code works perfectly.

```
menuBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();
        }
});

    //마우스로 매뉴를 잡고 움직일 수 있게 해주는 코드.
menuBar.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getXOnScreen();
            int y = e.getYOnScreen();
            setLocation(x - mouseX, y - mouseY);
        }
});
```

However, this doesn't

```
menuBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getXOnScreen();
            int y = e.getYOnScreen();
            setLocation(x - mouseX, y - mouseY);
        }       
});
```

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 2):

You *can* just use a `MouseAdapter`, but you have to call `addMouseMotionListener` so that mouse-motion events will get sent to it.

```
MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getXOnScreen();
        int y = e.getYOnScreen();
        setLocation(x - mouseX, y - mouseY);
    }
});
menuBar.addMouseListener(ma);
menuBar.addMouseMotionListener(ma);
```

Only a listener registered with `addMouseMotionListener` will be sent mouse-motion events, like dragging.

From the [MouseAdapter docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html):

> Create a listener object using the extended class and then register it with a component using the component's `addMouseListener`, `addMouseMotionListener`, `addMouseWheelListener` methods.

Comment: Sure it does. The OP's MouseAdapter was not receiving drag events because they didn't call `addMouseMotionListener`. If they called it, it would work.

Comment: MouseAdapter also has a mouse dragged method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html and the OP is confused as to why it doesn't do the same thing as the mousemotionlistener's method that is called the same thing

Comment: Excuse me, I'm talking crap as usual XD pls edit your answer so I can change my vote...